# list stored procedures that can be called by each user

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

i need a query to list every stored procedure that can be executed by a specific user and This for each user of my mssql server 2005.

output example:

`sa:`

`sp_MSrepl_startup`

`sp_MScleanupmergepublisher`

`administrator:`

`xp_foo`

`sp_bar`

Any help will be appreciated

phillipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be [sp_helprotect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190310.aspx) but it's legacy

This is SQL Server 2005+, but the code here quite basic and would need expanded as needed:

```
SELECT
    SUSER_SNAME(u.sid), OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id)
FROM
    sys.database_permissions p
    JOIN
    sys.database_principals u ON p.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id
```

If the DB user has rights on the code without a role, or nested roles, this can get ugly quickly...